# Magento is not loading my block

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions, blocks

I am using magento 1.7.2 version i am working on payment gateway a strange problem. please help me to out this problem here is following my `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Infeenty_InfeentyInvoice>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Infeenty_InfeentyInvoice>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <infeentyinvoice>
                <class>Infeenty_InfeentyInvoice_Model</class>
            </infeentyinvoice>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <infeentyinvoice_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Infeenty_InfeentyInvoice</module>
                    <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </infeentyinvoice_setup>
            <infeentyinvoice_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </infeentyinvoice_read>
            <infeentyinvoice_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </infeentyinvoice_write>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <infeentyinvoice>
                <class>Infeenty_InfeentyInvoice_Block</class>
            </infeentyinvoice>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <infeentyinvoice>
                <class>Infeenty_InfeentyInvoice_Helper</class>
            </infeentyinvoice>
        </helpers>
   </global>
   <default>
        <payment>
            <infeentyinvoice>
                <model>infeentyinvoice/infeentyinvoice</model>
                <countries>SE,DE,NL</countries>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>Infeenty Invoice</title>
                <active>1</active>
                <payment_action>authorize</payment_action>
            </infeentyinvoice>
        </payment>
        <payment_action>authorize</payment_action>
    </default>
    <adminhtml>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Infeenty_InfeentyInvoice>
                    <files>
                        <default>Infeenty_InfeentyInvoice.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Infeenty_InfeentyInvoice>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <infeentyinvoice>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Infeenty_InfeentyInvoice</module>
                    <frontname>infeentyinvoice</frontname>
                </args>
            </infeentyinvoice>
        </routers>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Infeenty_InfeentyInvoice>
                    <files>
                        <default>Infeenty_InfeentyInvoice.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Infeenty_InfeentyInvoice>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

strange issue might be did something wrong in this xml when i use
`$this->getLayout()->createBlock('infeentyinvoice/form')` then its always return false

i have create block file `Form.php` under `Infeenty/InfeentyInvoice/Block` and class is `Infeenty_InfeentyInvoice_Block_Form` but still i am not getting this block work

Comment: Do you have the file `app/etc/modules/Infeenty_InfeentyInvoice.xml`? Did you clear the cache after creating the module?

Comment: yes i have file in this location

Answer (score 19):

This looks correct. Troubleshooting steps, in order; do each one independently:

1. Clear cache. Disable compiler.
2. `var_dump(Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('infeentyinvoice/form'));` - If this returns "Mage_Infeentyinvoice_Block_Form", your module config XML is not being merged:

   - Enable developer mode (`Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true)`) and PHP error display, and break your `config.xml` file to confirm ~~it's being merged~~ that the configuration XML is being compiled without error.
   - Once this is returning the expected classname,
3. `var_dump(mageFindClassFile('Infeenty_InfeentyInvoice_Block_Form'));` - if this returns `false`, there is a problem with the path, syntax, or with file permissions.

   - Fix path / syntax / file permissions
4. `new Infeenty_InfeentyInvoice_Block_Form;` - if this returns false or some error, there is an issue with class definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('infeentyinvoice/form')->toHtml();
```

If you want to set a template use this

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('infeentyinvoice/form')->setTemplate('pathtotemplatefile/filename.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Comment: no its generating fatel error `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('infeentyinvoice/form')` return false so we can't call function

Comment: if you can post the error somebody will be able to help you.and i will tell you to check whether your block is working with minimal xml configuration to get blocks working. so you will get a better idea